# Odata post always returns "HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed,"

Tags: odata

Using the latest EF6 and Microsoft.OData I made controllers using the "web API 2 OData Controller with actions, using Entity Framework"

The get works fine but the POST always returns "HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies)"

It does not even get to the post section of the controller.

Does any one have a clue what can be wrong?

Thank you Much

Comment: Since the `Get` works fine, I assume you know this, but to be safe: OData's routing is case sensitive. As such, you need to make sure that the  EntitySet listed in your URL maps exactly to what you configured using `ODataConventionModelBuilder`'s `EntitySet<T>()` method. There was [a question on this earlier today that might be useful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30740084/odata-web-api-404-error/30741232#30741232).

Comment: Would you please share some codes?